# How to use Jquery and other scripts in ASP.NET MVC 5 Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller to return items from a partial view and want to use jQuery and select2, but when I add the scripts in the partial view, it doesn't work. The jQuery and the css files are not working.

Here is part of my code:

```
public ActionResult Admins(int admId)
{
    var alladmins = data.admins(admId)               
                        .Select(x => new Item(x))
                        .ToList();
    return PartialView("_Admins", alladmins)
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlSearch").select2();
   });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
 <label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="IP" value="Progress" checked="checked">
 Progress   
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
  <label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="pending" value="Pending">
 Pending 
 </label>
 </div>
 
<div id="select" class="Search">
  <div>
  <span id="adminSearch">Administrators</span> <br>
 <select name="ddlSearch" id="ddlSearch" class="form-control">
 <option value="" selected>--Select A Administrator--</option>
 </select>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your Jquery/Javascript scripts/references and CSS styles/references within layout file instead of partial view. Since, partial view is not a page reload therefore it will not render any of your scripts or styles available on the partial page, instead it will sync itself with those scripts and style which are already loaded at full page load/reload.

Comment: I have already included the Jquery/Javascript scripts/references and CSS styles/references within layout file but still not getting into the partial view

Comment: Include the relevant scripts and CSS files inside the main page from within your partial page view is clicked.

Comment: The issue I am having is, if I call  @Html.Partial("_Admins", alladmins) from a View Jquery works but if I call directly  return PartialView("_Admins", alladmins) from the controller then Jquery doesn't work. It loads only css files.